# HTMLElement.querySelector() using cheerio

Tags: javascript, cheerio

Using vanilla JavaScript, you can write

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
const button = box.querySelector(".button");
```

How about Cheerio?
I want to do something like:

```js
const box = $(".box");
const button = box.$(".button")
```

I'm asking because I have to loop over elements then find an anchor tag within that element:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(stdout)
      const boxes = $(".box").map((i, element) => element)
      boxes.each((i, element) => ?? maybe element.querySelector("a") )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use `descendant combinator` you can use [find](https://cheerio.js.org/Cheerio.html#find):

```
const button = box.find("button");
```

Comment: I'm facing an error saying "TypeError: element.find is not a function"

Comment: my code: `boxes.each((i, element) => urls.push(element.find("a").attr('href')))`

Comment: try with $(element).find("a")